# Infinite sum when a series is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been given the series:

$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}\frac{1}{(4+a)^n}$$

Which I need to find the sum $S$ for when the series is convergent. I would appreciate also an explanation on how to find the sum or pointing me in the right direction.

I have found out that the series is convergent for:
$$a  \in \; ]-\infty;-5[  \; \cup \; ]-3;+\infty[$$

Comment: How did you get to this conclusion ? What kind of series is that ?

Comment: Also, isn't that the symbol for 'and'? Maybe you have arrived at the same two statements for the range of $a$ connected by 'or'? And yes, how did you arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: Hint: look up geometric series

Comment: @barryCipra Yes, precisely that is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever, $(a+4) > 1 $, $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}\frac{1}{(4+a)^n} = \frac{1}{(a+4)} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{a+4}} 
= \frac{1}{a+3} $$ ( as , a GP series with ratio $\frac{1}{a+4} $ )

Whenever $(a+4) < -1 $ , $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}\frac{1}{(4+a)^n} =- \frac{1}{(a+4)} \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{a+4}} 
=- \frac{1}{a+5} $$ (as , a GP series with ratio $-\frac{1}{a+4} $ )

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting the series as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (4+a)^{-n}$. By multiplying by $(4+a)$ you'll get a new series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (4+a)^{-n}$. Subtracting the second series from the first gives you $(4+a)^1 = (4+a)$. Define $S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (4+a)^{-n}$ for simplicity (thinking of $S$ as the sum of the series). Then $S + (4+a)S = (4+a)$, and all you need to do is solve for the sum !